# Char array inputted from user to string conversion

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Ask user for char inputs then when user is done inputting enough char then the char array will be converted to string and returned as a string. Not sure where i went wrong but i think maybe at the looping part.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Character> charIn = new ArrayList<Character>();
        String word;
        boolean cond = false; 

        while (!cond) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a Character: ");
            charIn.add(sc.next().charAt(0));
            if (sc.next() == "0") {
                cond = true;
            }

        }
        word = charIn.toString();
        System.out.println(word);

    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are facing

Comment: What is going wrong ? what is your problem ? What is the input and the output ? Explain us your problem if you want us to help

Comment: You read the characters too often (one times you add it to charIn and one time in the if condition)

Comment: loop starts but it does not end. Also, "Please enter a character:" at output waits until i enter a character and then another one then loops and asks again. so i enter twice before it asks again

Comment: You do not need to initialize word to `""`. You do not need to re-affect cond to false in your loop. You could write `!cond` instead of `cond == false`

Comment: Have you tried to debug it ? because the problem is obvious when you debug

Comment: Will try and get back to u in a min

Comment: @Stewie If you change the question, the answers and comment won't be relative anymore. You add an infinite loop because of you re-assigned false to cond.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every time you call `sc.next()`, sistem will request form user input. call next once and put result to variable.
The problem is also in checking equality of string `next == "0"`. The truly equality of string objects in java is done across equals method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Character> charIn = new ArrayList<Character>();
            String word = "";
            boolean cond = false;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            while (cond == false) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a Character: ");
                String next = sc.next();
                charIn.add(next.charAt(0));
                if ("0".equals(next)) {
                    cond = true;
                }else{
                    cond = false;
                }

            }
            word = charIn.toString();
            System.out.println(word);

        }
}
```

Comment: and `cond == false` hum^^

Comment: Yes, the loop is infinite. And does not cut off

Comment: @Eugen thx for the update. The else part is useless since cond is already false

Comment: tried this code but it keeps asking me to enter a character but never breaks loop when cond becomes true on entering "0"

Comment: @vincrichaud what do we change in this code to make it right

Comment: The problem is also in checking equality of string next == "0". see update

Comment: It works now as expected when i changed code to the update you provided.

Comment: sorry, that i was not initially attentive

Comment: No problem. Thanks for taking time to answer :)